# 2 part Stored Procedure: Update based on TIME and then on latest date of linked rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I have an "order" table and need to amend shipping dates based on certain criteria where the logic cannot be applied upstream of it arriving in the database.

The table structure is so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[OrderNo] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
[CustomerCode] [varchar](32) NULL,
[DeliveryAddress1] [varchar](64) NULL,
[DeliveryAddress2] [varchar](255) NULL,
[DeliveryTown] [varchar](64) NULL,
[DeliveryCounty] [varchar](64) NULL,
[DeliveryPostcode] [varchar](10) NULL,
[DeliveryContact] [varchar](64) NULL,
[StockCode] [varchar](32) NULL,
[DespatchDate] [datetime] NULL,
[OrderReceived] [datetime] NULL
```

The logic is thus:

There are 3 x products for a specific customer:

Product A (data contained in [StockCode] field) has a lead time of 5 working days (the despatch date and time is defined in the [DespatchDate] field.)

Product B & C has a lead time of 4 working days.

If an order is received after 2pm, an additional day is added (the date and time an order is received is in the [OrderReceived] field).

If an order is placed that contains Product A and Product B or C, the 5 working day (or 6 working day is received after 2pm) should be applied to the product B and C lines.

The only way that orders with multiple items can be identified is if they are ordered on the same day and the delivery details are identical (each product will appear as a separate line in the order table).

I am looking for a stored procedure that will be called every 24 hours that will look at all orders placed in the last 24 hours (from the [OrderReceived] field) from customer "Example" ([CustomerCode] = 'Example')

Update the Order table and set the [DespatchDate] as 5 x working days from the OrderReceived date (where the time in [OrderReceived] is before 2pm and the [StockCode] = 'Product A', if order is received after 2pm it should be 6 working days). The same applies where the [StockCode] is 'Product B' or 'Product C' (but change the [DespatchDate] to 4 working days (or 5 working days if after 2pm).

The time on the [DespatchDate] should always be 19:00.

The 2nd part of the procedure would be to identify any orders that have been created in the last 24 hours that have matching delivery details ([DeliveryAddress1],[DeliveryAddress2],[DeliveryTown],[DeliveryCounty],[DeliveryPostcode],[DeliveryContact]) and update all the dates in the [DespatchDate] fields with the latest date. This fulfils the logic that anything ordered in last 24 hours going to the same person/location is a single order and should be shipped together on the same date.

Is that possible?

I am using a (slightly) similar stored procedure for another client, where we are changing the despatch dates to the next Thursday at 6pm based on the date information currently in that field:

```
UPDATE Orders

SET DespatchDate =  CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DespatchDate) = 1 then (dateadd(HOUR,(114),cast(floor(cast(DespatchDate as float)) as datetime))) 
                        When DATEPART(dw, DespatchDate) = 2 then (dateadd(HOUR,(90),cast(floor(cast(DespatchDate as float)) as datetime)))
                        When DATEPART(dw, DespatchDate) = 3 then (dateadd(HOUR,(66),cast(floor(cast(DespatchDate as float)) as datetime)))
                        When DATEPART(dw, DespatchDate) = 4 then (dateadd(HOUR,(42),cast(floor(cast(DespatchDate as float)) as datetime)))
                        When DATEPART(dw, DespatchDate) = 5 then (dateadd(HOUR,(18),cast(floor(cast(DespatchDate as float)) as datetime)))
                        When DATEPART(dw, DespatchDate) = 6 then (dateadd(HOUR,(162),cast(floor(cast(DespatchDate as float)) as datetime))) else
                        (dateadd(day,(5),cast(floor(cast(DespatchDate as float)) as datetime))) END
```

I am not sure how this can be applied in this case.

Hope you can help!

Comment: You have several problems here. First of all is you have different dates for different items. That is a clear indication that you should not be storing this date at the Order level. The second issue is that not all items on a single order will be sent the same day...and you can have several orders sent in the same delivery. This is a clear indication that once again you normalization issues. You should have a shipments table so that every order can have multiple shipments. This is really a many to many as any given shipment can contain parts of many orders.

Comment: And creating a stored procedure to continually update the despatch date is another indication of things gone left of center. You should not need to update this data automatically all the time like this. I think if you normalized your data properly the need to run, or even create, this new procedure would likely go away.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for the reply. Regarding the comment about dates at order level. You are correct, our standard workflow has a separate table where the "basket" information is stored, this filters into the order table for the individual items in the basket. In this case, we are receiving an XML punch out from a client ordering system, and the dates included are often incorrect. They also output a single XML item per line item (the basket table is always 1 row).

Comment: In this example, we do not have the facility to "correct" the XML at input stage, so were going down the route of correcting the data once in the database. We have the facility to group orders at despatch stage on common fields (e.g delivery addresses)

Comment: I should mention, the XML is being ingested via hot folder to create the "orders"

Comment: Can you explain this? "(dateadd(HOUR,(114),cast(floor(cast(DespatchDate as float)) as datetime)" What are you trying to do there? And you really need to be careful because floats are not exact numerics but maybe it doesn't matter here. Pretty sure that is just adding 114 hours to the current date. This might be a bit simpler to understand. dateadd(hour, 114, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())))

Comment: This relates to a service level agreement we have for a customer where we will always ship on the next Thursday at 6pm. The data we receive is linked to fixed lead times, and we "correct" that. The 1st part evaluates the day the current despatch date, and if it is Sunday, it adds 114 hours to 00:00 on the Sunday - SET DespatchDate =  CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DespatchDate) = 1 then (dateadd(HOUR,(114),cast(floor(cast(DespatchDate as float)) as datetime)))

Comment: We are using the hours to always set the time at 18:00